# SSL error when opening link in python. Works fine in browser

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl

Here is the code. Any idea what this link isn't working?

```
from requests import get
InputJson = urllib2.openurl('https://api.cilabs.net/v1/conferences/ws15/info/attendees?page=2')
```

Here is my error message

```
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error
```

I tried setting verify to false, as suggested by a previous post. But to no avail.

My python version is 2.7.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try upgrading the following libraries with pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
```